# Dynamically Sorting with LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a collection of CLR objects. The class definition for the object has three properties: FirstName, LastName, BirthDate.

I have a string that reflects the name of the property the collection should be sorted by. In addition, I have a sorting direction. How do I dynamically apply this sorting information to my collection? Please note that sorting could be multi-layer, so for instance I could sort by LastName, and then by FirstName.

Currently, I'm trying the following without any luck:

```
var results = myCollection.OrderBy(sortProperty);
```

However, I'm getting a message that says:

*... does not contain a defintion for 'OrderBy'  and the best extension method overload ... has some invalid arguments.*

Answer (score 10):

Okay, my argument with SLaks in his comments has compelled me to come up with an answer :)

I'm assuming that you only need to support LINQ to Objects. Here's some code which needs significant amounts of validation adding, but does work:

```
// We want the overload which doesn't take an EqualityComparer.
private static MethodInfo OrderByMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(method => method.Name == "OrderBy" 
           && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .Single();

public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByProperty<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    string propertyName) 
{
    // TODO: Lots of validation :)
    PropertyInfo property = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(propertyName);
    MethodInfo getter = property.GetGetMethod();
    Type propType = property.PropertyType;
    Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), propType);
    Delegate func = Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType, getter);
    MethodInfo constructedMethod = OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(
        typeof(TSource), propType);
    return (IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>) constructedMethod.Invoke(null,
        new object[] { source, func });
}
```

Test code:

```
string[] foo = new string[] { "Jon", "Holly", "Tom", "William", "Robin" };

foreach (string x in foo.OrderByProperty("Length"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Output:

```
Jon
Tom
Holly
Robin
William
```

It even returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>` so you can chain `ThenBy` clauses on as normal :)

Comment: How about `customers.OrderByProperty("LastName").ThenByProperty("FirstName")` or `customers.OrderByProperty("LastName", "FirstName")` (where these are `params string[]`), as it seems to be part of his requirement. Would that be workable in this solution?

Comment: @Anthony: You'd have to write more code to do that of course, but it would be possible - and look a lot like the code above.

Comment: OK. And as I'm someone who knows jack squat about the topic, is there a reason you would prefer reflection over @SLaks' use of expression trees? (In case I'm presented with such a requirement in the future.)

Comment: @Anthony: Well, my version works with LINQ to Objects directly - SLaks' version needs an `IQueryable<T>`. You can create one using the AsQueryable operator, but I would personally stick with this version.

Comment: @Jon, @Anthony: My version doesn't need an `IQueryable<T>`; you can just compile the expression.  However, it'll be slower than yours since it needs to compile an expression.  (which could be cached)

Comment: @SLaks: One other relevant point I hadn't mentioned before - your solution assumes the property type is the same for all properties. If that's actually the case, my code can be simplified significantly. If it's not the case, then you'll have to do similar generic reflection work :(

Comment: True.  (or use `object`, and cause boxing)

Comment: Is this safe to use in an enterprise app with a few thousand rows? I got it working and I also added a 'OrderByPropertyDescending' to Jon's solution. I'm just concerned though at "TODO: Lots of validation" heh. All I need is to sort an IEnumerable with strings as column name parameters - nothing fancier. Quite new to LINQ so maybe I misunderstood that comment about validation.

Comment: @user982119: Yes, it's fine to use this with thousands of rows. The validation would be a matter of checking that the specified property exists, is readable etc. That validation is only going to be performed once - not once per comparison.

Answer (score 7):

You need to build an [Expression Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) and pass it to `OrderBy`.
It would look something like this:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass));
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, PropertyType>>(
    Expression.Property(param, sortProperty),
    param
);
```

Alternatively, you can use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), which will allow your code to work as-is.

Comment: How do I build an Expression Tree?

Comment: Given that the OP has "a collection of CLR objects" I suspect he's not after an IQueryable solution.

Comment: @Jon: So what?  You still need an expression tree to sort dynamically.  That just means he'll need to call `Compile`.

Comment: @SLaks: I disagree. I think it's entirely possible to sort dynamically without an expression tree.

Comment: How applicable would this solution (or Jon's hypothetical solution) be if the type of `sortProperty` was not fixed?

Comment: @Anthony: My solution could easily be modified to produce objects.  Jon's would work as is, and would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void sort_grd(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["order"]) == true)
        {
            ViewState["order"] = false;

        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["order"] = true;
        }
        ViewState["SortExp"] = e.SortExpression;
        dataBind(Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["order"]), e.SortExpression);
    }

public void dataBind(bool ord, string SortExp)
    {
        var db = new DataClasses1DataContext(); //linq to sql class
        var Name = from Ban in db.tbl_Names.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             First_Name = Ban.Banner_Name,
                             Last_Name = Ban.Banner_Project
                         };
        if (ord)
        {
            Name = BannerName.OrderBy(q => q.GetType().GetProperty(SortExp).GetValue(q, null));
        }
        else
        {
            Name = BannerName.OrderByDescending(q => q.GetType().GetProperty(SortExp).GetValue(q, null));
        }
        grdSelectColumn.DataSource = Name ;
        grdSelectColumn.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with Linq

```
var results = from c in myCollection
    orderby c.SortProperty
    select c;
```

Comment: The problem is, my sortProperty is a string. How can I do a sort with a string like that?

Comment: ah, i see. Found another post here that may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275878/linq-how-to-dynamically-use-an-order-by-in-linq-but-only-if-a-variable-is-not-st

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of dynamic work I've been using the Dynamic LINQ library which makes this sort of thing easy:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx

Comment: I misunderstood, I've updated my answer to suggest using the Dynamic Linq library.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic sorting you could evaluate the string i.e. something like

```
List<MyObject> foo = new List<MyObject>();
string sortProperty = "LastName";
var result = foo.OrderBy(x =>
                {
                if (sortProperty == "LastName")
                    return x.LastName;
                else
                    return x.FirstName;
                });
```

For a more generic solution see this SO thread: [Strongly typed dynamic Linq sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557819/strongly-typed-dynamic-linq-sorting)

Comment: Agreed, it's not a very generic solution, but solves this particular problem

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use reflection to get the PropertyInfo, and then use that to build an expression tree. Something like this:

```
var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
var prop = entityType.GetProperty(sortProperty);
var param = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
var access = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, prop), param);

var ordered = (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>) Queryable.OrderBy(
    myCollection, 
    (dynamic) access);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste the method I post in that answer, and change the signature/method names:
[How to make the position of a LINQ Query SELECT variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861737/how-to-make-the-position-of-a-linq-query-select-variable/4875630#4875630)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use your original line of code

```
var results = myCollection.OrderBy(sortProperty);
```

simply by using the [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library.

If you get a compiler error (something like cannot convert from or does not contain a definition...) you may have to do it like this:

```
var results = myCollection.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortProperty);
```

No need for any expression trees or data binding.