# How to make the position of a LINQ Query SELECT variable

Tags: linq-to-sql, select, properties

Is it possible to make the LINQ SELECT more flexible by not working with properties but with the column name?
Maybe an example will help..I'm trying to do the following (pseudocode):

```
From x In Entities
Where ...
Select("ID", "Value" , "Date")
```

but depending on certain choices, I would like to have the result in different order

```
From x In Entities
Where ...
Select("Value", "Date", "ID" )
```

Or another amount of SELECT results

```
From x In Entities
Where ...
Select("Value")
```

Any help to make this as dynamic as possible would be AWESOME! tnx

Comment: what is it you are displaying the information in(a grid, drop down list, list view etc)

Comment: I guess you can write an Extension Method Select(params string[] columnNames), build the Expression Tree depending on names and Queryable generic type, and pass it to the Select<TSource,TResult>, but you'll loose typing, you'll have to return a IQueryable<dynamic>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you

```
from x In Entities
where ... select new {
  Value = x["Value"],
  Date = x["Date"],
  ID = x["ID"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment (handles subproperties, like Type.Name, but not multiple fields)
I let the fun to make the multi field version ;)

```
public static class DynamicLinkExtensions
{    
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Select<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string memberAccess)
    {
        var propNames = memberAccess.Split('.');
        var type = typeof(T);
        var props = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        foreach (var propName in propNames)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(propName);
            props.Add(prop);
            type = prop.PropertyType;
        }
        return source.Select(props.ToArray());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Select<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, PropertyInfo[] props)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, (MemberInfo)props.First());

        for (var i = 1; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(member, (MemberInfo)props[i]);
        }

        Expression<Func<T, object>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(member, new[] { parameter });
        return source.Select(expression);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var names = DataContext.Customers.Select("Name").Cast<string>().ToList();
```