# sort gridview with dynamic linq

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with several columns, 3 of which I'd like to sort.
The source for the data is held in the session.

```
protected void MyGridHistorySort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    var TheColumn = (e.SortExpression).ToString();

    TheDataHistory = (List<ViewDataHistoryModel>)Session["SessionDataHistory"];

    var test = "data.DataDate";

    var NewDataSource = from data in TheDataHistory
                    orderby test
                    select data;

    MyGridHistory.DataSource = NewDataSource;
    MyGridHistory.DataBind();
```

DataDate is a valid column in the list but the orderby statement doesn't work. Ideally, I'd like it to sort with the variable TheColumn by writing something like test = "data."+TheColum; and then add a sort direction based on a boolean. I looked at the OrderBy extension method NewDataSource.OrderBy(test); but that doesn't work either.

What am I missing to make my code work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to have

```
var NewDataSource = from data in TheDataHistory
                    orderby data.DataDate
                    select data;
```

Since the orderby clause takes a property name. The clause doesn't parse the string to determine what to order by like Dynamic Queryable does.

Or, in the case of sorting on multiple fields, I would use

```
var NewDataSource = from data in TheDataHistory
                    select data;

switch(fieldToSortOn)
{
  case "field1":
    NewDataSource = NewDataSource.OrderBy(x => x.Field1);
    break;
  case "field2":
    NewDataSource = NewDataSource.OrderBy(x => x.Field2);
    break;

  ...

}
```

If you are really bent on just using a string to sort this, then I would totally recommend the [Dynamic Queryable](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode48DynamicQueryableMakesCustomLINQExpressionsEasier.aspx) library. I've been using it and it's perfect for what I've been doing lately (with some added support for DateTime? objects)

Then you can do things like

```
NewDataSource = NewDataSource.DynamicOrderBy("ID DESC, Name DESC, Price ASC");
```

Love this library!

Comment: Yea, that works for one column but I'd like to make it work for all the other column and have the orderby take a string parameter. How does the OrderBy extension method work?

Comment: What I would probably do in this case is use the same statement, only without the orderby clause, then have a switch statement that orders them by whatever field is passed in via the arguments. I'm editing my answer to show this...

Comment: I just did it with the switch clause. I know there must be a better way to do it but for now it works. Sub-optimal code but that's ok for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/09/18/dynamic-string-based-queries-in-linq.aspx) for this expression:

```
string sortExpression = "ContactName DESC";     
var x1 = context     
    .Customers    
    .OrderBy(sortExpression);
```

Comment: That's already what I'm doing and that's what's not working. The OrderBy doesn't seem to take a string as a parameter, even with the ASC or DESC.

Comment: So you've downloaded the Dynamic.cs file, included it in your project and use the System.Linq.Dynamic namespace? Because standard Linq doesn't support dynamic expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste the code in my answer and change the Select to OrderBy and dynamic to T ;)
[How to make the position of a LINQ Query SELECT variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861737/how-to-make-the-position-of-a-linq-query-select-variable/4875630#4875630)