# DataGrid sorting with column text change C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

How to dynamically sort data in DataGridView in Windows Forms when we are entering data to a column header?

Comment: question is not clear, please describe more clearly

Comment: What do you mean by "when we are entering data to a column header"? You want to sort the data when the column header text is changed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878490/sort-gridview-with-dynamic-linq

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes when we are changing the DataGridView  Header dynamically.I found this in old foxpro application now i converting into the windows based application

Comment: hi @ArsenMkrt  it's like sorting data when we are entering some data in to the column header or first column in the dgv..

Comment: What do you sort by? Or do you mean you want to *filter* data dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to bind `DataGrid` to [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) and after use its [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) property to query **data**, as `DataGrid` is binded to that data, the content of it will be updated automatically.