# Ascending and descending of list object in c# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, telerik-grid

I have a `telerikgrid` in which all the columns are sortable by `asc` and `desc`. Now I have a `list` object which binds to the `datasource` of the grid and I have to `sort` the columns. Here I'm passing the column name and expression for sorting.

//Code

```
public List<TelerikBookingRequestingColumns> Select(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortExpressions, List<GridFilterExpression> filterExpressions)
        {
            int numberOfObjectsPerPage = maximumRows;

            List<TelerikBookingRequestingColumns> objList = new List<TelerikBookingRequestingColumns>();
            objList.AddRange(list);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpressions))
            {
                string firstExpression = sortExpressions.Split(',')[0];

                var queryResultorderby = (from listObject in objList
                                          orderby firstExpression 
                                          select listObject);   

               objList= queryResultorderby.ToList<TelerikBookingRequestingColumns>();
            }

            var queryResultPage = (from listObject in objList
               .Skip(startRowIndex)
               .Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage)
                                   select listObject);

            return queryResultPage.ToList<TelerikBookingRequestingColumns>();



        }
```

In the above code the `firstExpression` will be like (empid asc) or( empid desc) which means a column name and the `sort` expression. But this doesn't works.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out Jon Skeet's answer in "Dynamically Sorting with LINQ": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726047/dynamically-sorting-with-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[orderby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) requires lambda for key selector:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

but you are trying to pass simple string. This will not work. Try to use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) if you want to sort results based on some string.

---

Get [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) from NuGet and apply sorting this way (assume firstExpression looks like *propertyname* + *asc/desc*):

```
var firstExpression =  "empid asc";
var queryResultorderby = objList.AsQueryable()
                                .OrderBy(firstExpression);
```

Comment: I'm confused to make your code to mine. Can u post the complete code which works. Need like the code to implement please.

Comment: @Sandy I described you reason why your code will not work, and provided link for library which meets your needs. Have you visited that link? Or you want just copy-paste solution without thinking?

Comment: @Sandy glad to see you solved problem :) I'll add complete sample for others