# Entity generic pagination

Tags: c#, entity-framework, pagination

I have to query all rows in one table. In one shot, the query is too long, I get a timeout. So I wanna run this query in several batch using pagination. But to do `size` and `take` orderby is required. And that is the problem, how make the order by generic (maybe on the primary key) ? Or is there a way without order by ?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetListBatchLoadingAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> iWhere = null, long iSize) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        IQueryable<T> theQueryable = RepositoryDBContext.Set<T>();

        //Where clause
        if (iWhere != null)
            theQueryable = theQueryable.Where(iWhere);

        //batch loading
        Int64 entitiesCount = await theQueryable.CountAsync();
        int totalPage = (int)Math.Ceiling(decimal.Divide(entitiesCount, iSize));

        //query
        var result = new List<T>();
        for (int a = 0; a < totalPage; a++)
             result.AddRange(await  theQueryable.OrderBy(x=>x. ????).Skip(TAKECOUNT * (a)).Take(TAKECOUNT).ToListAsync());

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a paging extension that might be useful to you. Specifically, I think the generic IOrderedQuerable illustrates how you can make the OrderBy generic:

```
public static IPagedEntities<T> WithPaging<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery, int page, int pageSize)
{
    var totalEntities = orderedQuery.Count();

    var entities = orderedQuery.Skip((page * pageSize)).Take(pageSize);

    return new PagedEntities<T>(page, pageSize, totalEntities, entities);
}
```

It's use would be as follows:

```
// base query
var query = _dbContext.SomeItems.AsQueryable();

var orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(t => t.SomeProperyToOrderBy);

// pages the results
// the WithPaging extension method requires an IOrderedQueryable
// (orderedQuery) which is produced by calling OrderBy on an IQueryable<T>
var withPaging = orderedQuery.WithPaging(yourDesiredPage, yourDesiredPageSize);
```

The IPagedEntities just wraps an IEnumerable with some extra metadata related to the paging operation. It's not terribly relevant to your question, but I included it for completeness:

```
public interface IPagedEntities<out T>
{
    int Page { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    int TotalSize { get; }
    int Pages { get; }
    int NumberSkipped { get; }
    int? NextPage { get; }
    int? PriorPage { get; }
    int FirstPage { get; }
    int LastPage { get; }
    bool OnFirstPage { get; }
    bool OnLastPage { get; }
    bool HasNextPage { get; }
    bool HasPreviousPage { get; }

    IEnumerable<T> Entities { get; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. But my biggest problem is to set the orderby keyselector in a generic way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a primary key set (which you should have on all tables if you're using EF), you can do this:

```
var keyProperty = typeof(YourEntityClass).GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(KeyAttribute)));
```

This will essentially look at your EF model and choose the column that is marked as the primary key. You can replace YourEntityClass with your `T` value if you're using generics. You can pull the name out of the keyProperty with .Name and use that in your orderby statement (you may want to use extended linq and specify `propName + " ASC"` for example, or build an expression tree).

Alternatively, you could use the Partial classes of your entity model to have an interface such as `IExposesPrimaryKey` and implement something that returns the name of the primary key.

Comment: How about composite primary keys?

Comment: I understand how you retrieve the propertyInfo of the key, but how should I use it in the orderby ? How transform it in keyselector ?

Comment: @Julian50: You can either build an expression tree from scratch, or use a library like [dynamic LINQ](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) to make it easier.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Do you any example please ? I'm not used to do it... :)

Comment: @Julian50: There are plenty of examples out there, if you search for them. Did you read the link that I provided? If you want to build your own expression tree, here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4726173/120955

Comment: I think you'd have the most luck with dynamic LINQ, just NuGet it into your project and add the appropriate `using` statement, and `OrderBy` will then take an overload of a string, and you can do my suggested `propName + " ASC"`